# grep >word anywhere in the file

Tags: grep

How can I grep >word where word could be any word without grepping word? For ex, if word if appel, I would like to retrieve all lines >appel and not appel. How about if the lines starting with >word (and again not word)?

Thanks

Carol

Comment: please give a real world example with data.  Your question as it stands is not clear

Comment: Seven questions (before this one) with zero votes and zero accepted answers. Do you know how StackOverflow works?

Comment: Lines that have the word appel and not the word appel would be every line. Please clarify what you want, and what your `>appel` notation means.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to use `grep`'s `^` *anchor*, which matches start-of-line.  E.g., if your `input` file has lines such as the following

```
>appel
appel
```

then

```
$ grep '^>appel' input
```

will return

```
>appel
```